# Match text blocks enclosed by newlines

Tags: python, regex

I have a file in the format of always three lines followed by an empty line. Which regex would match such blocks of three lines?

```
line1
line2
line3

line4
line5
line6
...
```

I know that `^\s*$` can match a line which only contains white space so something like `^\s*$(.*)^\s*$` should match something in between two empty lines, but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What regex patterns have you tried? Why do you need to use a regex if it is always an empty line every fourth line?

Comment: Why not just use `str.split('\n\n')`?

Comment: @niemmi: `str.split()` maybe not viable if the file is large

Comment: @mhawke: True, I was just advocating `str.split` over regex for such a simple task since the were no comments about the file size in original question.

Comment: str.split('\n\n') would result in a newline as the last element of the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `itertools.islice()` to read the file 4 lines at a time, and throw away the last line if it is a newline:

```
from itertools import islice

with open('input') as f:
    while True:
        lines = [line.strip() for line in islice(f, 4) if line.strip()]
        if not lines:
            break
        print(lines)    # or otherwise process them
```

**Demo**

With this input:

```
line1
line2
line3

line4
line5
line6

line7
line8
```

the output is

```
['line1', 'line2', 'line3']
['line4', 'line5', 'line6']
['line7', 'line8']
```

This also handles the case that the file ends without a full group of 3 lines.

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of Python's [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) function to read the lines until an empty line is found as follows:

```
from itertools import groupby

with open('input.txt') as f_input:
    for k, g in groupby(f_input, lambda x: x != '\n'):
        if k:
            print [line.strip() for line in g]
```

This would then read each three lines as a block. If though there were extra empty lines, these would also be skipped, or if there were more than three lines in a block these would also be read as a single block.

This would print the following:

```
['line1', 'line2', 'line3']
['line4', 'line5', 'line6']
```

Comment: I like this. It is more flexible than my `islice()` solution and memory efficient on large files.